# QML Clip Custom Item

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I made my own QQuickItem, which I draw using the updatePaintNode method (using the scenegraph). In a qml File I add this item as a child to a Rectangle:

```
    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width/2.
        height: parent.height/2.
        border.color: "#000000"
        clip: true

        MyItem {
            id: myitem
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onWheel: {
                    if (wheel.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier) {
                        parent.scale = parent.scale+ 0.2 * wheel.angleDelta.y / 120;
                        if (parent.scale < 1)
                            parent.scale = 1;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I added a zoom function and set

```
    clip: True
```

for the rectangle. However, when I zoom, my item is not clipped at the Rectangle but extends beyond it. What would be the correct way to do clipping?

Edit: Here is the content of the cpp file for MyItem

```
MyItem::MyItem(QQuickItem *parent): QQuickItem(parent)
{
    setFlag(QQuickItem::ItemHasContents,true);
    // code to initialize xdata, ydata, xmax, ymax

}

QSGNode *MyItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData *) {
    QSGGeometryNode *mypath = static_cast<QSGGeometryNode*>(oldNode);
    if(!mypath) {
       mypath = new QSGGeometryNode;
       mypath->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsMaterial,true);
       mypath->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsGeometry,true);
    }
    QSGGeometry *geometry = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_Point2D(),_xdata.size());
    QSGGeometry::Point2D *points = geometry->vertexDataAsPoint2D();
    for(int i=0;i<_xdata.size();i++) {
    points[i].x = _xdata[i]/_xmax*width();
    points[i].y = _ydata[i]/_ymax*height();
    }
    geometry->setLineWidth(2);
    geometry->setDrawingMode(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    mypath->setGeometry(geometry);
    QSGFlatColorMaterial *material = new QSGFlatColorMaterial;
    material->setColor(Qt::blue);
    mypath->setMaterial(material);
    return mypath;
}
```

and here is the header file:

```
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <vector>

class MyItem : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyItem(QQuickItem *parent = 0);

private:
    std::vector<double> _xdata;
    std::vector<double> _ydata;
    double _xmax;
    double _ymax;

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    QSGNode * updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData *data) override;
};
```

Comment: It works with Qt Quick items like `Text`, so we'd probably need to see the C++ for your custom item.